# Angular Cannot find name 'Angular' Visual Studio 2015 Dotnet MVC web app

Tags: angularjs, angular, npm, visual-studio-2015, angular-bootstrap

So I am new in angular and i am working on visual studio 2015 update 3. 
Simple Angular app work perfectly on VS2015 dotnet MVC project.
I have a problem when i downgradecomponent in app.module.ts file

```
angular.module('app').directive('viewTest', downgradeComponent({ component: ViewTestComponent }));
```

error is on angular it says cannot find name 'angular'

my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "angular-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation, supplemented with testing support",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -p src/",
    "build:watch": "tsc -p src/ -w",
    "build:e2e": "tsc -p e2e/",
    "serve": "lite-server -c=bs-config.json",
    "serve:e2e": "lite-server -c=bs-config.e2e.json",
    "prestart": "npm run build",
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"npm run serve\"",
    "pree2e": "npm run build:e2e",
    "e2e": "concurrently \"npm run serve:e2e\" \"npm run protractor\" --kill-others --success first",
    "preprotractor": "webdriver-manager update",
    "protractor": "protractor protractor.config.js",
    "pretest": "npm run build",
    "test": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "pretest:once": "npm run build",
    "test:once": "karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "lint": "tslint ./src/**/*.ts -t verbose"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~4.3.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~4.3.4",
    "@angular/core": "~4.3.4",
    "@angular/forms": "~4.3.4",
    "@angular/http": "~4.3.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~4.3.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.3.4",
    "@angular/router": "~4.3.4",
    "@angular/upgrade": "~4.3.4",

    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.3.0",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.5.10",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.2.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "~2.8.1",

    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "lodash": "^4.16.4",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~4.0.14",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",

    "@types/node": "^6.0.46",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.36"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

I also declare this.

```
declare var angular: any;
```

by doing that project run with no error. but nothing is rendering. 
when i inspect element in browser it show me the converted component but not rendering any other angularjs component.

need help thanks

Comment: If you are new to angular why you are starting with angularjs... start with Angular 2+. https://angular.io/tutorial  https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

Comment: i am new in angular. app is already in angularjs upgrading the app. so this is happening

Comment: @OkashaRafique Same problem :( have you solved this problem yet?